# Who should recite Akdamut in the synagogue?

Tags: prayer-book, shavuos

**Optimally**, who should lead the reading of Akdamut in the synagogue on the 1st day of Shavuot. Should it be:

- the *chazzan* (cantor)
- the *Ba'al Kri'ah* ( Torah reader )
- The Cohen (who receives the 1st aliyah)
- The *gabbai* who calls up the oleh
- The rabbi
- Someone else
- It does not matter

Comment: The Meturgemman would be best, seemingly.

Comment: Just took a quick look, neither the Mishna Berurah nor the Aruch Hashulchan sticky who says Amdamus. From a practical purpose, the Bal Koreh is probably the best one to do it, as it's done together with Krias Hatorah and it's the type of thing that requires a bit of practice to do, and the Bal Koreh is likely a good candidate for that.

Comment: @Salmononius2 In the past 2-3 years, I, as the Ba'al Kri'ah have done it in my shul. I'm not thrilled about doing it, though. With the way the ARamit is, it sounds like I'm speaking Klingon, and I have no teeth left :-)

Comment: The Rav normally reads it in our Schul, but I would think that the main qualification is to get your teeth round the Aramaic (as DanF mentioned) accurately. I would think that the Cohen is a bad choice, because IIRC, there is a minhag to read Akdamut _after_ the brachah (although many, even most read before to avoid hefsek)

Comment: The minhag is that the baal koreh does it (except where there is a rebbe). I think the meturgamon (in the olden times or perhaps in some places even today) is not allowed to be the baal koreh because people will think the targum is written in the torah. This applies to akdamus.

Comment: @newcomer The meturgeman may seem to be the most obvious as the Targum was in Aramit. But, you make a very valid point in your 2nd sentence that I think may be mentioned directly in the Gemarah (prob. Mas. Megillah). I'll see if I can locate it. Re Akdamut - not sure, esp. if it is said before the Cohen makes the Bracha. Perhaps, you and I can research further to see the order of how Akdamut was originally done. I suspect that if the original practice was to say it after the bracha, then your statement has extremely strong support.

Comment: Fwiw, in at least two synagogues in my experience, the _baal k'ria_ (Torah reader) reads lines n+1 and n+2, and the congregation reads lines n+3 and n, for integer values of n, except that everyone reads the last line. (It's possible that the _baal k'ria_ reads the congregation's lines also. I've never noticed.)

Comment: @msh210 As a Ba'al Kri'ah, I used to read it in my shul until about 3 years ago. Since then, they've asked the chazzan to do it. I guess they like his voice better? If we explained the usage of "n" to the mostly seniors in my cong., I think they would give up, immediately. Of the few that have dentures to pronounce the rough Aramaic, and can actually say it, directing them to say alternate two lines, is an easier explanation.

Comment: In my kehillah, of the first 88 lines, the ba'al korei reads the first two lines, the kehillah reads the next two, and so forth, and for the last two lines, the ba'al korei reads the first and the kehillah reads the last.

Comment: What do you mean by optimally? This is not a Halakhic obligation. Why should any custom be better than another?

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_37057_39.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different Minhagim as to who reads Akdamus.
[Nitei Gavriel](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46443&st=&pgnum=152&hilite=) quotes the Yaavetz (among others) who writes that some shuls ensure that someone other than the baal korei reads it. This is reminiscent of the times when shuls would have an interpreter ('meturguman') translate the Chumash into the vernacular.

Comment: To be clear Akadamut was written for a Meturgeman. Everything else is just later made up stuff.

Comment: @DoubleAA, what's the "everything else" that wasn't written for a מתורגמן?

Comment: @msh all other akdamut reading practices